# Me toma el width y height dentro de la etiqueta pero no en la hoja externa de css, porque podra ser?

Tags: img, height, width

Me toma el width y height dentro de la etiqueta pero no en la hoja externa de css, porque podra ser?
.
Quiero pasar el w y h en la hoja de css sacarlo de la etiqueta para hacer una lectura mas limpia del html.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Cuál etiqueta,, cuál hoja? Cuál HTML? Por favor incluye el código relevante yendo a [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Faltarían ejemplos de como lo estás haciendo o que estás haciendo exactamente, para ver si tienes algún error.

El css te está bien enlazado a la página, está funconando?

Estás utilizando el tag,clase,id para seleccionar la img en el css?

Sin más te pongo un ejemplo que funciona a ver si te sirve.

```css
img{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
```